# No email templates getting loaded Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: php, email, magento-1.9.3.2

I am using Magento 1.9.3.2

When I go to System > Transaction Emails > Add new Template

In the Add new Template form No default templates are getting displayed

See the image for reference (Image 1.1),
[image: Image 1.1]

How to solve the issue. Because in earlier versions the drop down box was showing all of the default email templates

Comment: There seems to be some error on your page because there is no footer section. Please check your error logs. If you enable developer mode, it will display you the error on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its definitely some issue in creating a new email template.
Same issue happen to me and when i check this, i found the Helper file is missing.
Just inspect the template drop down and see what is the error showing there.